# Servlets - Break out of loop when button is clicked?

Tags: java, servlets

I have this loop in a Java Servlet class:

```
...
out.println("<button type=\"submit\">Stop!</button>");
...
for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
            response.getWriter().println(i+1 + ". Hello<br/>");
            response.flushBuffer();
}
```

The page that is produced looks like this:

[image]

Each line is printed incrementally to the screen. How can I make it so that I break out of the loop when the button is clicked? In other words, if the user clicks "Stop" when line 3 is printed, it should break out of the loop.

PS: I would like to do this using servlets. I have a good reason for not using JSPs.

Comment: If you are wanting real-time user interation, then consider using javascript.  Servlets are not going to be able to achieve this

Comment: Button presses happen on the client. Which won't finish loading the page until your servlet finishes. So no. This will not work. Also, embedding html in your servlets (regardless of not wanting to use JSPs) is **not** the answer.